# Estimating the standard deviation

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, noise, functional-data-analysis

I have data of a function $f(t)$, where I always have just a single data point per $t$. It is known that the data is affected by noise, where the noise itself is also a function of $t$. Now I want to estimate the standard deviation of the noise for different $t$. What methods could I use to do this?

Comment: Hey, fun question (+1), please see my answer below! You came across *[Functional Data Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_data_analysis)* (or at least a slightly primitive application of it!). Let me know if you want any clarifications.

Comment: Do you have any prior information on your data or noise ?

Comment: @Lelouch No, I don't have any information about the noise / data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe appears to be a good scenario to estimate the "*functional variable process*" of the data. A formal treatment of the matter can be found in Mueller et al. (2006) [*Functional Variance Processes*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/016214506000000186).

To succinctly describe how we would the above methodology here: We assume a smooth underlying mean function: $\mu_Y(t)$ and estimate it as $\hat{\mu}_Y(t)$, *non*-parametrically via local linear smoothing from our observed data $f(t)$. We then calculate the (observed) residuals: $R(t)$ as $f(t) - \hat{\mu}_Y(t)$,  and then square and log them such that we have the observed transformed residuals: $Z(t) = \log(R^2(t))$. Again assuming a smoothing underlying mean function *for the variance* we once estimate it as $\hat{\mu}_Z(t)$ based on the observed $Z(t)$. To quote the paper directly: "*As in the case of regression residuals, the squared errors $R^2_{ij}$ can be expected to carry relevant information about the random variation, and the exponential factors convey the nonnegativity restriction*" (of the variance). Notice here that, Mueller et al. expect to have multiple realisations of the underlying process, that's why they index by $i$ as well as $j$. In the case of a single process (i.e. just one $f(t)$) the $i=1$ but we still have $J$ measurement points. And that's about it! We have our variance function in: $\mu_Z(t)$ (or $\mu_V(t)$ to use the same notation as the paper). Taking the square root of it gives us our standard deviation along $t$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! This was very helpful.

Comment: Great! I am happy I could help. :)